# Automated script to validate a verification code

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using javascript to create automated testing for a B2C sign-up policy. I am using mailosaur as an inbox to receive my verification code to complete the email registration. My script is similar to the below-pasted script. This can help me validate the message that's been successfully sent to the inbox however, I would want to add an additional fixture where the script can copy just the **verification code** (The body of the message would look like "your code is: XXXXXX") sent to the generic inbox and paste it back to a registration page to complete the user registration. Please advise how can this be achieved? Many Thanks

```
import uuidv4 from "uuid/v4";
import MailosaurClient from "mailosaur";

import signUpModel from "./page_models/sign_up_model";

const client = new MailosaurClient("<MAILOSAUR API KEY>");
const mailosaurServerId = "<MAILOSAUR SERVER ID>";
const emailAddress = `${uuidv4()}@dev-tester.com`;

fixture("Airport Gap Signup Flow")
  .page("https://airportgap-staging.dev-tester.com/tokens/new")
  .beforeEach(async () => await client.messages.deleteAll(mailosaurServerId));

test("User receives an email after signup", async t => {
  await t
    .typeText(signUpModel.emailInput, emailAddress)
    .typeText(signUpModel.passwordInput, "airportgap123")
    .click(signUpModel.submitButton);

  await t.wait(10000);

  let message = await client.messages.get(mailosaurServerId, {
    sentTo: emailAddress
  });

  await t.expect(message.to[0].email).eql(emailAddress);

  await t.expect(message.subject).eql("Here's your generated token");

  await t
    .expect(message.html.body)
    .contains("Here's your newly generated Airport Gap token");
});
```

Comment: It seems like you need to parse the message. Can you show us how the email body looks like? Have you already tried something? If so, please add it to your question s well.

Comment: I didn't come up with any solution yet. The body of the message looks like the following: Verify your email address
 
  
Thanks for verifying your XXXXXXXXXX account!

Your code is: XXXXX


Sincerely,
B2C Dev

Answer (score 3):

It could be as simple a task as parsing some text:

```
const text = "Verify your email address Thanks for verifying your XXXXXXXXXX account! Your code is: 09876 Sincerely, B2C Dev";
const code = text.match(/Your code is: [0-9]+/)[0].split(':')[1].trim();
console.log(code);
```

This will output `09876` into a console.

1/ To match your code in the message:

```
text.match(/Your code is: [0-9]+/)
```

2/ To split it by colon:

```
[0].split(':')
```

3/ To get only the numbers (the code itself) and remove whitespace:

```
[1].trim()
```

I'd most likely create a helper function and wrap this code in it, so the test case is less polluted.

---

You can look up these methods on MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim

Comment: Thank you for the snippet to parse the message of the body. I would appreciate it if you can explain how can the parsed code can be entered on the registration page. In the above example, It should copy the code and paste it back to a field in the registration page https://airportgap-staging.dev-tester.com/tokens/new

Comment: I don't see any registration page. Is `typeText()` a solution for you?

Comment: Sorry above link doesn't have the registration option but my application is for signing-up a new user. My script has to emulate the following...Enter the email account, verify the code that's been sent to their email by pasting it back to the sign-up screen and click verify code. typeText() can be used but not sure how to specify within typeText() to paste the value that it parsed.

Comment: You are already using `typeText()` in your script, use it in a similar way on the signup page.